# Is it possible to set the x86 flags to Carry=Sign=Overflow=1 with one addition insn?

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

I am programming using the AT&T notation on the i386 architecture.

Is it possible to add two 8-bit numbers in order to set the Carry, Overflow, and Sign Flags to be set, using a single `add` instruction?

I am thinking it is impossible to get this flag combination. In order for the S-flag to be set together with the O-flag, the most significant bits of both numbers would have to be 0 and the most significant bit of the result would have to be 1. That leaves us with no way to generate a carry from the addition of the most significant bits.

This is my first time asking a question on this site, so I apologize if I did anything wrong. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I can ONLY use the following three instructions:

```
movb $_, %ah
movb $_,%al 
addb %ah,%al
```

I have to modify the two underscores with decimal values.

EDIT: Out of CF, OF, SF, and ZF, I can only have CF, OF, and SF set. I cannot have the Carry Flag set.

(editor's note: That last sentence makes no sense.  Is that a typo for Parity or Zero Flag, or maybe he means CF can't be set *before* the `addb`?  It's `add`, not `adc`, so it doesn't depend on the previous state of flags.  Leaving this as an edit instead of requesting clarification in a comment because it's an old question that might not get a response.  Please edit out this note if/when you fix that sentence about "cannot have the Carry Flag set", Shan.)

Comment: I'm sure it can be hacked without addition.

Comment: It's for a homework assignment so that won't work? Haha!

Comment: I see. I'll think on this.

Comment: The combination of CF=SF=OF=1 is impossible to achieve from adding any two bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **impossible** to set CF=SF=OF=1 with `add ah, al`. A formal proof is going to be somewhat lengthy, but a simple exhaustive test confirms the impossibility of such a combination of flag states after an `add` instruction.

---

You can use `POPF(D)` to set an arbitrary combination of arithmetic flags. This instruction will pop a (d)word from the stack and write it into `(E)FLAGS`.

Note that there are other, unrelated to arithmetic, flags in the flags register. You shouldn't generally modify them. So, you'd typically first read the value of the register (using `PUSHF(D)`), modify that as necessary and then write back as outlined above.

Comment: `sahf` doesn't modify `OF`, so it needs to be set separately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just updated the question to make it clear about which instructions I am allowed to use.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexey. I just wanted to confirm that this case is impossible. This is what I wrote in my original question:        I am thinking it is impossible to get this flag combination. In order for the S-flag to be set together with the O-flag, the most significant bits of both numbers would have to be 0 and the most significant bit of the result would have to be 1. That leaves us with no way to generate a carry from the addition of the most significant bits.

Is that the correct reasoning for this case being impossible?

Comment: You beat me to it. A formal proof may be lengthy, but a "brute force" search is fast and easy. I did the brute force search and proved it's impossible.

Comment: No need for a formal proof. I just need to explain in my homework assignment if the case is impossible and I think have a good explanation for that. Again thanks to everyone who contributed to the answer. I just signed up on this website and you guys are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Using only `add al,ah` or any other `add` it is impossible.

You can do it by popping `flags` / `eflags` into some register, then setting the flags you want with `or`, pushing the register and popping it into flags.

For 16-bit code (NASM syntax):

```
pushf
pop ax
or ax,0x881
push ax
popf
```

For 32-bit code:

```
pushfd
pop eax
or eax,0x881
push eax
popfd
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just updated the question to make it clear about which instructions I am allowed to use.

Comment: `or [esp], 0x881` would be more efficient that pop/push.  Also, you could do something to set OF, then `SAHF/modify AH/LAHF`.