# x86 instructions to set parity, overflow, & sign flags

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

We have the `STC` instruction to set the carry flag. Do we have similar instructions for parity, overflow, sign flags etc? I have tried `STP`, `STS` etc but it seems these don't exist!

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15330350/3857942

Comment: _"I have tried these STP, STS etc"_ Instead of guessing whether an instruction exists, look it up in [Intel's instruction set manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE.  The other answer asks if one can set all three *at the same time*.  Completely different question, completely different answer.  I WISH CLOSERS WOULD READ THE QUESTIONS CAREFULLY BEFORE THEY SLAM THE DOOR SHUT.

Comment: @IraBaxter : That was actually the reason I didn't vote to close and provided a link to another SO answer that was related (but not a duplicate). Some of the information in the answers can be used to solve this question, but it definitely isn't a duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

No, those commands don't exist.  The way you find out is by reading the instruction reference manuals carefully.

They don't really *need* to exist.
You can effectively implement them pretty easily.
Here's one of many ways, if you don't mind other bits getting set:

```
STP:  XOR  AL,AL  ; resets parity bit
      XOR  AL,1   ; ... then set parity bit

STO:  OR   AL, 0FFh
      SUB  AL, 080h ; sets overflow

STS:  OR   AL, 0FFh ; sets sign bit
```

If you insist on setting just the specific bit:

```
      PUSHFD
      OR    dword ptr[ESP], <bitmask_for_flag_bit> ; see Intel manual
      POPFD
```

Silicon space being precious, CPU designers tend not to provide instructions for things that are easily done.  (STC is left over from 8080 days, where it was useful in doing various kinds of multiprecision arithmetic and not damaging registers was a Very Good Thing).

Comment: You can clear parity and sign flags without clobbering a register, by doing `test al, 0`.  The result of `0 AND x` is always zero, so the old contents of `al` don't matter.  Also, you can set PF with `OR AL, 0FFh`, regardless of previous contents.  Also, other than the overflow flag, `SAHF/modify AH/LAHF` is more efficient than pushfd/popfd.

Comment: @PeterCordes: OP asked for how to *set* these bits; I agree with your scheme to clear them.   How does OR AL 0FFH clear *set* the parity bit?  There are *8* one bits, that's *even* parity.   I offered PUSHFD sequence for those cases where you can't damage the registers.

Comment: Oh, brain fart, you're right about PF.  I was thinking "FF is an odd number" or something.  And good point about not `pushf` not clobbering regs.  The shift instructions have interesting interactions with flags, but always in a data-dependent way that doesn't help for coming up with single-instruction sequences.